# how to edit front end without plugins in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP website with template files having static html content but now I need that content to be editable from WP back end.

I am aware about the_content and custom fields but the content that we have is not at one fixed place so can we have a front-end edit button after every content area in a page on click of which a popup with content editor will open and I can edit and update that content. I

Comment: Hey! You need to put your code here whatever you have tried so far. StackOverflow community cannot help you in writing code from scratch. You need to put your code here then we'll help you debug that code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn Wordpress theme development. You can get a quick start from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Here are some basic functions that you need to use in your theme files to display dynamic content from backend.

```
wp_head(); /* https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head */

the_content(); /* https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/ */
the_excerpt(); /* https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/ */

wp_footer(); /* https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer */

get_the_header();  /* https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header */
get_the_footer();  /* https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer */
wp_enqueue_style(); /* https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/ */
```

these are some of most used functions in wordpress. which will help you  to get dynamic contents from wordpress backend.